# Qubes-OS install Qubes support tools in HVM to fix screen resolution and copy paste

Tags: virtual-machine, xrandr, qubes

I want to install a fully virtualized machine (HVM) with Kali Linux in Qubes-OS. The installation itself was a bit bumpy but I managed to install it correctly.

Now, the issue is that I want to increase the screen size and use copy pasting between the other Qubes and this HVM. If I compare this to VMWare or Virtualbox, the logic thing to do is to install the "guest addon's" which make copy pasting possible and fix the display issue. For Qubes OS this is called "Qubes support" as far the documentation mention this. The max screen size in the VM possible is 1920x1080, but I have a bigger screen. Inside the VM i tried to use `xrandr` to increase it, I managed to get it a bit bigger but not as big as I want (at a certain limit the VM shows a black screen).

---

The commands I used:
First we use `gtf` for calculating the modeline of possible resolutions:

```
gtf <xres> <yres> <refresh> [-x]
```

Give the desired values for x-resolution, y-resolution and refresh rate. The flag -x is default and can be omitted. For a portrait resolution 480x640 at 60 Hz you will get the following output:

```
$ gtf 480 640 60 -x
$ 480x640 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 39.78 kHz; pclk: 24.82 MHz Modeline "480x640_60.00" 24.82 480 504 552 624 640 641 644 663 -HSync +Vsync
```

From this we can copy & paste the modeline to add it to xrandr list of known resolutions:

```
xrandr --newmode "480x640_60.00" 24.82 480 504 552 624 640 641 644 663 -HSync +Vsync
```

and:

```
xrandr --addmode VBOX0 480x640_60.00
```

Replace `VBOX0` with the appropriate monitor.

---

I am unsure on how to install Qubes support tools in a linux machine, the documentation only mentions Windows. Any dev's out there that know how to do this?